# Adding a dynamic +1 to phone number as user enters it on form

Tags: javascript, regex, format, phone-number

I work for a company that gathers leads from the internet. Potential customers send us inquiries that include their phone number. We're having a problem because some folks are including a +1 at beginning. The code I already have there allows only 10 digits, and their last digit on phone number isn't getting sent. (ex: instead of receiving this: (987) 654-3210 it's (198) 765-4321 (the last digit, '0', wasn't included) FYI: I already re-format it on backend to look like this: +19876543210. It has to be in that format when it's stored in our CRM so we can use text functionality in a web browser to communicate.

I used the code below to mask/format the phone number, but I'm trying to tweak it for a desired result, but no such luck. I tried adding an extra digit to the end, which would allow proper phone formatting on the back end, but it'll look like this to the eye (987)654-32107, and I'm afraid folks will get confused, get frustrated and leave before submitting an inquiry.

```
HTML: <input type="text" value="" name="telephone" id="telephone">

JS: <script>
document.getElementById('telephone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
   var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
   e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
</script>
```

I'd like to make it as "dummy proof" as possible without a validation "flag." I want it to include the '1' whether the user enters it or not.  Anyone ever have this problem?

Comment: Why are you formatting as the user types? Your code produces a horrific experience for anyone that needs to change a digit in the middle of their input

Comment: Not sure why you're saying that. The backspace buttons work fine with this. But I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: Enter `1234567890` and delete the 4 and 5 or replace them with a different number. https://jsfiddle.net/486nrk0x/

Comment: I see your point, but we had the field just allowing numbers before... and our conversions dropped. So, any solution to my actual problem?

Comment: Yes, use a library which has the kinks figured out already. https://imask.js.org/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8c5anxsu/1/ seems to elegantly do what you describe.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I was hoping for just some code, but I'll look into that. I did a lot of searching yesterday and imask never came up. Thanks for sharing.  And, yes, your jsfiddle is exactly what I wanted. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: No problem, there are lots of "input masking" libraries available, I guess you just need to Google the correct terms. I'm glad you're going forward with using a library instead of trying to contrive your own solution with kinks :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, there's still one aspect I need. If someone actually manually types a 1 first, it's still not getting their last digit in the phone number. We'd still get +1(198) 765-4321. Can a '1' simply be prevented from being entered if it's the first digit?